# Laravel API can't update Microsoft Dynamic Nav Customer

Tags: laravel-5, dynamic

I have a Laravel API hitting a MS Nav instance to carry out some data shuffling and migration between two systems. I am able to create Customer records in Nav just fine, but am running into some issues with updating.

I am able to perform a single `PATCH` request to update a customer record by any subsequent requests return the following error message.

```
{
    "odata.error":{
        "code":"",
        "message":{
            "lang":"en-US",
            "value":"Another user has already changed the record."
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what my PHP code looks like if that makes a difference.

```
/**
 * @param string $navNo
 * @param string $eTag
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
public function updateCustomer($navNo = '', $eTag = '', $data = []) {
    $url = $this->config['uri'] . ':' . $this->config['port'] . '/' . $this->config['server'] . '/' . $this->config['service'] . '/CustomerCardPage';
    $url .= "('$navNo')" . '?$format=json&company=' . $this->config['company'];

    $options = [
        'auth'    => $this->config['auth'],
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'If-Match'     => 'W/"\'' . $eTag . '\'"',
        ],
        'json'    => $data,
    ];

    return $this->makeRequest('PATCH', $url, $options);
}

/**
 * @param $method
 * @param $url
 * @param $options
 * @return array
 */
private function makeRequest($method, $url , $options) {
    $response = ['success' => true, 'data' => null, 'error' => null];

    try {
        $res = $this->client->request($method, $url, $options);

        $body = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);
        $response['data'] = $body;
    } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
        $res = $e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents();

        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['error'] = $res;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I haven't been able to dig up anything helpful in the Nav support forums. Has anyone else run into this type of issue with Laravel/PHP or any other back-end language/framework?

**Disclaimer:** I have absolutely 0 experience with MS Dynamic Nav, nor do I have direct access to the Nav dashboard or whatever you would call it.

Here are the versions of the relevant framework/packages/services I am working with:

- Laravel: 5.6
- Guzzle: 6.3
- Nginx: 1.13.6
- Nav: ...? Can bug someone to find out if this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The ETag is updated each time the customer updates since it acts as a version control. The error was basically telling me that I can't update the version because it was already updated previously.

To fix, just make sure to update the customer ETag after updating.